# Drawing Sphere in OpenGL without using gluSphere()?

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

Are there any tutorials out there that explain how I can draw a sphere in OpenGL without having to use `gluSphere()`?

Many of the 3D tutorials for OpenGL are just on cubes. I have searched but most of the solutions to drawing a sphere are to use `gluSphere()`. There is also a site that has the code to drawing a sphere at [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20111203145224/http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/cs/490/sched/feb8/) but it doesn't explain the math behind drawing the sphere. I have also other versions of how to draw the sphere in polygon instead of quads in that link. But again, I don't understand how the spheres are drawn with the code. I want to be able to visualize so that I could modify the sphere if I need to.

Comment: look up spherical coordinates for the math explanation (specifically the conversion from spherical coordinates to cartesian coordinates).

Answer (score 295, accepted):

One way you can do it is to start with a platonic solid with triangular sides - an [octahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron), for example. Then, take each triangle and recursively break it up into smaller triangles, like so:

[image: recursively drawn triangles]

Once you have a sufficient amount of points, you normalize their vectors so that they are all a constant distance from the center of the solid. This causes the sides to bulge out into a shape that resembles a sphere, with increasing smoothness as you increase the number of points.

Normalization here means moving a point so that its angle in relation to another point is the same, but the distance between them is different.
Here's a two dimensional example.

[image]

A and B are 6 units apart. But suppose we want to find a point on line AB that's 12 units away from A.

[image]

We can say that C is the normalized form of B with respect to A, with distance 12. We can obtain C with code like this:

```
#returns a point collinear to A and B, a given distance away from A. 
function normalize(a, b, length):
    #get the distance between a and b along the x and y axes
    dx = b.x - a.x
    dy = b.y - a.y
    #right now, sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) = distance(a,b).
    #we want to modify them so that sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) = the given length.
    dx = dx * length / distance(a,b)
    dy = dy * length / distance(a,b)
    point c =  new point
    c.x = a.x + dx
    c.y = a.y + dy
    return c
```

If we do this normalization process on a lot of points, all with respect to the same point A and with the same distance R, then the normalized points will all lie on the arc of a circle with center A and radius R.

[image: bulging line segment]

Here, the black points begin on a line and "bulge out" into an arc.

This process can be extended into three dimensions, in which case you get a sphere rather than a circle. Just add a dz component to the normalize function.

[image: normalized polygons]

[image: level 1 bulging octahedron]
[image: level 3 bulging octahedron]

If you look at the sphere at [Epcot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_Earth_%28Epcot%29), you can sort of see this technique at work. it's a dodecahedron with bulged-out faces to make it look rounder.

Comment: I'd rather remove the link to the epcot sphere. It may confuse beginners because there every triangle is again subdivided into three isosceles triangles (similar to the first part of sqrt(3)-subdivision). I'm sure you find a better example.

Comment: I have a nice implementation of this on my home machine. I'll be happy to edit in some screenshots after work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I don't understand the part on how by normalising the vectors, I could bulge the sides out into a shape that resembles the sphere? How do I bulge the sides out?

Comment: @xEnOn, I've edited my answer to explain normalization a little more. I think the problem is that normalization isn't the actual technical term for the process I was trying to explain, so it would be difficult for you to find more information on it anywhere else. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why is this the only good description of this technique? Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe a better way to explain the "normalization" process here is that the points are being projected onto a sphere. Also, note that the results differ depending on whether the normalization/projection is applied just once at the end (after all subdivision, which seems to be what is being suggested here) or interleaved with the (recursive) subdivision steps. It appears that projecting just once at the end yields vertices clustered near the vertices of the initial octahedron, whereas interleaved subdivision and projection yields uniform distances between vertices.

Comment: Love the animations! Especially how they *change* rotations direction ;)

Comment: Your code is horrible, doesn't respect the parametric equation, the idea is nice though.

Comment: Unfortunately the solutiion present here is only part/half of it.

Comment: Sub division of triangles is missing.

Comment: This link has good information for the missing parts: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html#name8

Comment: @TylerStreeter If you're aiming for least deformation in projecting the points to a sphere, you may want to start out with a rhombic triacontahedron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1080/17538947.2022.2130459

Comment: @魔大农 Very cool! I was not aware. Thanks for these links.

Answer (score 32):

I'll further explain a popular way of generating a sphere using latitude and longitude (another
way, *icospheres*, was already explained in the most popular answer at the time of this writing.)

A sphere can be expressed by the following parametric equation:

**F**(*u*, *v*) = [ cos(u)*sin(v)*r, cos(v)*r, sin(u)*sin(v)*r ]

Where:

- *r* is the radius;
- *u* is the longitude, ranging from 0 to 2π; and
- *v* is the latitude, ranging from 0 to π.

Generating the sphere then involves evaluating the parametric function at fixed intervals.

For example, to generate 16 lines of longitude, there will be 17 grid lines along the *u* axis, with a step of
π/8 (2π/16) (the 17th line wraps around).

The following pseudocode generates a triangle mesh by evaluating a parametric function
at regular intervals (this works for *any* parametric surface function, not just spheres).

In the pseudocode below, *UResolution* is the number of grid points along the U axis
(here, lines of longitude), and *VResolution* is the number of grid points along the V axis
(here, lines of latitude)

```
var startU=0
var startV=0
var endU=PI*2
var endV=PI
var stepU=(endU-startU)/UResolution // step size between U-points on the grid
var stepV=(endV-startV)/VResolution // step size between V-points on the grid
for(var i=0;i<UResolution;i++){ // U-points
 for(var j=0;j<VResolution;j++){ // V-points
 var u=i*stepU+startU
 var v=j*stepV+startV
 var un=(i+1==UResolution) ? endU : (i+1)*stepU+startU
 var vn=(j+1==VResolution) ? endV : (j+1)*stepV+startV
 // Find the four points of the grid
 // square by evaluating the parametric
 // surface function
 var p0=F(u, v)
 var p1=F(u, vn)
 var p2=F(un, v)
 var p3=F(un, vn)
 // NOTE: For spheres, the normal is just the normalized
 // version of each vertex point; this generally won't be the case for
 // other parametric surfaces.
 // Output the first triangle of this grid square
 triangle(p0, p2, p1)
 // Output the other triangle of this grid square
 triangle(p3, p1, p2)
 }
}
```

Comment: The down vote seems a bit harsh. It is one of the only answers with and example that mentions discrete construction via the sphere's parametric equation. It may also be easier to understand on the basis that a sphere may be regarded as a stack of circles that shrink as they near the poles.

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to point out that the second of each value of p0, p1, p2, p3 should be either v or vn, as opposed to u or un.

Answer (score 10):

The code in the sample is quickly explained. You should look into the function `void drawSphere(double r, int lats, int longs)`:

```
void drawSphere(double r, int lats, int longs) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i <= lats; i++) {
        double lat0 = M_PI * (-0.5 + (double) (i - 1) / lats);
        double z0  = sin(lat0);
        double zr0 =  cos(lat0);

        double lat1 = M_PI * (-0.5 + (double) i / lats);
        double z1 = sin(lat1);
        double zr1 = cos(lat1);

        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for(j = 0; j <= longs; j++) {
            double lng = 2 * M_PI * (double) (j - 1) / longs;
            double x = cos(lng);
            double y = sin(lng);

            glNormal3f(x * zr0, y * zr0, z0);
            glVertex3f(r * x * zr0, r * y * zr0, r * z0);
            glNormal3f(x * zr1, y * zr1, z1);
            glVertex3f(r * x * zr1, r * y * zr1, r * z1);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

The parameters `lat` defines how many horizontal lines you want to have in your sphere and `lon` how many vertical lines. `r` is the radius of your sphere.

Now there is a double iteration over `lat`/`lon` and the vertex coordinates are calculated, using simple trigonometry.

The calculated vertices are now sent to your GPU using `glVertex...()` as a `GL_QUAD_STRIP`, which means you are sending each two vertices that form a quad with the previously two sent.

All you have to understand now is how the trigonometry functions work, but I guess you can figure it out easily.

Comment: @PintoDoido: It was from OP's original link which died at some point; I Archive.org'd the link & edited the function into this answer for clarity.

Comment: The radius is missing.

Comment: The first parameter "double r" is not used.

Comment: That is correct. The code sample is not part of my original answer. @genpfault: you added the code sample in an edit. Can you please fix the example?

Comment: @Constantinius: Will do; not quite sure where the `r` usage went missing though...

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: This code is concise and works well. There's also some fun tricks you can play with it. For instance, lat = 2, with large longs - you get a double-cone.  With lat=2 and long=4, you get an octahedron.  Reduce the number of iterations in the outer for-loop and you get partial spheres (divide by 2 to get a hemisphere).

Comment: Normals seem incorrect, pointing inward instead of outward.

Comment: Swapping the order of vertex code appearance fixes the normals, except for bottom and top circle, strange.

Comment: Another drawback is in polygon mode with lines setting, each line seems to be drawn twice.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to be sly like a fox you could half-inch the code from GLU. Check out the MesaGL source code (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/).

Comment: Whilst I understood the meaning of "half-inch" in this context, I think you might want to edit it for the other 95% of readers who aren't fluent in [cockney rhyming slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang)!

Answer (score 2):

See the OpenGL red book: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html#name8
It solves the problem by polygon subdivision.

Answer (score 2):

My example how to use 'triangle strip' to draw a "polar" sphere, it consists in drawing points in pairs:

```
const float PI = 3.141592f;
GLfloat x, y, z, alpha, beta; // Storage for coordinates and angles        
GLfloat radius = 60.0f;
int gradation = 20;

for (alpha = 0.0; alpha < GL_PI; alpha += PI/gradation)
{        
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (beta = 0.0; beta < 2.01*GL_PI; beta += PI/gradation)            
    {            
        x = radius*cos(beta)*sin(alpha);
        y = radius*sin(beta)*sin(alpha);
        z = radius*cos(alpha);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        x = radius*cos(beta)*sin(alpha + PI/gradation);
        y = radius*sin(beta)*sin(alpha + PI/gradation);
        z = radius*cos(alpha + PI/gradation);            
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);            
    }        
    glEnd();
}
```

First point entered (glVertex3f) is as follows the parametric equation and the second one is shifted by a single step of alpha angle (from next parallel).

Comment: Has issues with bottom, in line mode, perhaps drawing it twice, not sure, some kind of normal issue. Also one line is visible vertically.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
   void draw_sphere(float r)
    {
    
        float pi = 3.141592;
        float di = 0.02;
        float dj = 0.04;
        float db = di * 2 * pi;
        float da = dj * pi;
    
    
        for (float i = 0; i < 1.0; i += di) //horizonal
            for (float j = 0; j < 1.0; j += dj) //vertical
            {
                float b = i * 2 * pi;      //0     to  2pi
                float a = (j - 0.5) * pi;  //-pi/2 to pi/2
    
    
                //normal
                glNormal3f(
                    cos(a + da / 2) * cos(b + db / 2),
                    cos(a + da / 2) * sin(b + db / 2),
                    sin(a + da / 2));
    
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                //P1
                    glTexCoord2f(i, j);
                    glVertex3f(
                        r * cos(a) * cos(b),
                        r * cos(a) * sin(b),
                        r * sin(a));
                //P2
                    glTexCoord2f(i + di, j);//P2
                    glVertex3f(
                        r * cos(a) * cos(b + db),
                        r * cos(a) * sin(b + db),
                        r * sin(a));
                //P3
                    glTexCoord2f(i + di, j + dj);
                    glVertex3f(
                        r * cos(a + da) * cos(b + db),
                        r * cos(a + da) * sin(b + db),
                        r * sin(a + da));
                //P4
                    glTexCoord2f(i, j + dj);
                    glVertex3f(
                        r * cos(a + da) * cos(b),
                        r * cos(a + da) * sin(b),
                        r * sin(a + da));
                glEnd();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where to put radius in ?

Comment: Does not seem to work in GLScene with GLMesh acquiring these verteces.

Comment: For now I call flawed on this, until radius is put into it, the texture option is a little bit interesting though.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer solves the question, there's a little misconception at the end. **Dodecahedrons** are (or could be) regular polyhedron where all faces have the same area. That seems to be the case of the Epcot (which, by the way, is not a *dodecahedron* at all). Since the solution proposed by @Kevin does not provide this characteristic I thought I could add an approach that does.

A good way to generate an N-faced polyhedron where all vertices lay in the same sphere *and* all its faces have similar area/surface is starting with an icosahedron and the iteratively sub-dividing and normalizing its triangular faces (as suggested in the accepted answer). Dodecahedrons, for instance, are actually [*truncated* icosahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron).

[Regular icosahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron) have 20 faces (12 vertices) and can easily be constructed from 3 golden rectangles; it's just a matter of having this as a starting point instead of an octahedron. You may find an example [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html#name8).

I know this is a bit off-topic but I believe it may help if someone gets here looking for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Python adaptation of @Constantinius answer:

```py
lats = 10
longs = 10
r = 10

for i in range(lats):
    lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + i / lats)
    z0 = sin(lat0)
    zr0 = cos(lat0)

    lat1 = pi * (-0.5 + (i+1) / lats)
    z1 = sin(lat1)
    zr1 = cos(lat1)

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP)
    for j in range(longs+1):
        lng = 2 * pi * (j+1) / longs
        x = cos(lng)
        y = sin(lng)

        glNormal(x * zr0, y * zr0, z0)
        glVertex(r * x * zr0, r * y * zr0, r * z0)
        glNormal(x * zr1, y * zr1, z1)
        glVertex(r * x * zr1, r * y * zr1, r * z1)

    glEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a quad that faces the camera and write a vertex and fragment shader that renders something that looks like a sphere. You could use equations for a circle/sphere that you can find on the internet.

One nice thing is that the silhouette of a sphere looks the same from any angle. However, if the sphere is not in the center of a perspective view, then it would appear perhaps more like an ellipse. You could work out the equations for this and put them in the fragment shading. Then the light shading needs to changed as the player moves, if you do indeed have a player moving in 3D space around the sphere.

Can anyone comment on if they have tried this or if it would be too expensive to be practical?

Comment: That's only true under a parallel projection. If you use a perspective projection, the silhouette of the sphere in the rendering output is **not** generally a circle.