# WebGL recursive Sphere out of Octhedron

Tags: javascript, recursion, geometry, webgl

trying to generate, based on a provided recursionDepth, a sphere-like shape. Somehow I really struggle with the generation of the indices lines & triangles within the recursion. The vertices seem to be generated just fine, but the triangles and lines are only partially completed, which gives me e.g. for recursionDepth 2 the following image.

```
var octahedron = (function () {

    function midpoint(v1, v2) {
        return [
            (v1[0] + v2[0]) / 2,
            (v1[1] + v2[1]) / 2,
            (v1[2] + v2[2]) / 2
        ];
    }

    function normalize(v) {
        var length = Math.sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2]);
        return [v[0] / length, v[1] / length, v[2] / length];
    }




    function createVertexData(recursionDepth) {
        // Positions.
        originVertices = new Float32Array([
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  // Vertex 0: Top
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  // Vertex 1: Front-right
            -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Vertex 2: Front-left
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  // Vertex 3: Front-bottom
            0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  // Vertex 4: Back-bottom
            0.0, -1.0, 0.0   // Vertex 5: Bottom
        ]);

        // Index data for triangles.
        originIndicesTris = new Uint16Array([
            0, 1, 3,  // Top-front-right triangle
            0, 3, 2,  // Top-front-left triangle
            0, 2, 4,  // Top-back-left triangle
            0, 4, 1,  // Top-back-right triangle
            5, 3, 1,  // Bottom-front-right triangle
            5, 2, 3,  // Bottom-front-left triangle
            5, 4, 2,  // Bottom-back-left triangle
            5, 1, 4   // Bottom-back-right triangle
        ]);


        // Normals.
        originNormals = new Float32Array([
            // Top vertex
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            // Bottom vertex
            0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
            // Front vertex
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            // Back vertex
            0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
            // Left vertex
            -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            // Right vertex
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        ]);

        // Index data for lines.
        originIndicesLines = new Uint16Array([
            0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0,  // Top face
            0, 3, 3, 1,  // Front face
            0, 4, 4, 2,  // Back face
            5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5,  // Bottom face
            5, 2, 2, 4,  // Left face
            5, 4, 4, 1   // Right face
        ]);



        // Subdivide each triangle and move the new vertices to the surface of a sphere.
        this.vertices = originVertices;
        this.normals = originNormals;
        this.indicesLines = originIndicesLines;
        this.indicesTris = originIndicesTris;

        function subdivideGeometry(recursionDepth, indicesTris, vertices) {
            if (recursionDepth <= 0) {
                // Base case: No further subdivision required
                return;
            }

            let newVertices = [];
            let newNormals = [];
            let newIndicesTris = [];
            let newIndicesLines = [];

            // Subdivide each triangle and normalize the new points
            for (var i = 0; i < indicesTris.length; i += 3) {
                var v1 = vertices.subarray(indicesTris[i] * 3, indicesTris[i] * 3 + 3);
                var v2 = vertices.subarray(indicesTris[i + 1] * 3, indicesTris[i + 1] * 3 + 3);
                var v3 = vertices.subarray(indicesTris[i + 2] * 3, indicesTris[i + 2] * 3 + 3);

                var m12 = midpoint(v1, v2);
                var m23 = midpoint(v2, v3);
                var m31 = midpoint(v3, v1);

                m12 = normalize(m12);
                m23 = normalize(m23);
                m31 = normalize(m31);

                newVertices.push(...v1, ...m12, ...m31, ...v2, ...m23, ...m12, ...v3, ...m31, ...m23, ...m12, ...m23, ...m31);
                newNormals.push(...v1, ...m12, ...m31, ...v2, ...m23, ...m12, ...v3, ...m31, ...m23, ...m12, ...m23, ...m31);


                var baseIndex = newVertices.length / 3 - 4;
                console.log('index' + i)
                newIndicesTris.push(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 3, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3, baseIndex, baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 3);
                newIndicesLines.push(baseIndex, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex, baseIndex + 3, baseIndex + 1, baseIndex + 3, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 2, baseIndex + 3);

            }

            // Recursive call with decreased depth
            var recursiveResult = recursionDepth > 1 ? subdivideGeometry(recursionDepth - 1, new Uint16Array(newIndicesTris), new Float32Array(newVertices), new Float32Array(newNormals), new Uint16Array(newIndicesLines)) : null;


            // Combine recursive result with current result
            if (recursiveResult) {
                newVertices = Array.from(recursiveResult.vertices);
                newNormals = Array.from(recursiveResult.normals);
                newIndicesTris = Array.from(recursiveResult.indicesTris);
                newIndicesLines = Array.from(recursiveResult.indicesLines);
            }

            console.log(recursionDepth);
            // Updating the geometry data structures

            console.log("newVertices: " + newVertices.length);

            return {
                vertices: new Float32Array(newVertices),
                normals: new Float32Array(newNormals),
                indicesTris: new Uint16Array(newIndicesTris),
                indicesLines: new Uint16Array(newIndicesLines)
            }

        }

        if (recursionDepth > 0) {
            // Call the recursive function
            let updatedGeometryData = subdivideGeometry(recursionDepth, this.indicesTris, this.vertices, this.normals, this.indicesLines);

            this.vertices = updatedGeometryData.vertices;
            this.normals = updatedGeometryData.normals;
            this.indicesTris = updatedGeometryData.indicesTris;
            this.indicesLines = updatedGeometryData.indicesLines;

        }
    }

    return {
        createVertexData: createVertexData
    }
}());
```

I've tried digging a bit into the algorithm but would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing Sphere in OpenGL without using gluSphere()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687148/drawing-sphere-in-opengl-without-using-glusphere)

Comment: here [recursive sphere triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214) similar QA ...