# calculating a sphere in opengl

Tags: opengl, geometry

I want to calculate all the vertices needed and connect them with lines, so I eventually come up with a sphere. How many ways are there to do it? And also the lines between the vertices, will be straight; how can I make them "curved" I know that I can use glutWireSphere(), but I am interested in actually calculating the vertices. A way that I thought about it, was to put all the vertices manually in an array, but I guess that is not the way it's done.

Comment: Be sure to check out the well-known magnificent page by Andreas Kahler, http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html

Comment: You can draw _curved_ primitives, not by using vertices, but by using an entirely different paradigm: [distance functions in a _fragment shader_](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm). This is strictly non-beginner material, though, so be warned! =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copy and Pasting some code I originally wrote in [Creating a 3D sphere in Opengl using Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988686/how-do-i-create-a-3d-sphere-in-opengl-using-visual-c/5989676#5989676)

```
class SolidSphere
{
protected
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    std::vector<GLfloat> normals;
    std::vector<GLfloat> texcoords;
    std::vector<GLushort> indices;

public:
    void SolidSphere(float radius, unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors)
    {
        float const R = 1./(float)(rings-1);
        float const S = 1./(float)(sectors-1);
        int r, s;

        sphere_vertices.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        sphere_normals.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        sphere_texcoords.resize(rings * sectors * 2);
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator v = sphere_vertices.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator n = sphere_normals.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator t = sphere_texcoords.begin();
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
                float const y = sin( -M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R );
                float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );
                float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );

                *t++ = s*S;
                *t++ = r*R;

                *v++ = x * radius;
                *v++ = y * radius;
                *v++ = z * radius;

                *n++ = x;
                *n++ = y;
                *n++ = z;
        }

        sphere_indices.resize(rings * sectors * 4);
        std:vector<GLushort>::iterator i = sphere_indices.begin();
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
                *i++ = r * sectors + s;
                *i++ = r * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + s;
        }
    }

    void draw(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_vertices[0]);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_normals[0]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_texcoords[0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, sphere_indices.size()/4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sphere_indices);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

> how can I make them "curved"

You can't. All OpenGL primitives are "affine", i.e. planar or straight. Curvature is emulated by drawing short, straight sections with sufficient resolution.

Comment: The sphere produced by your code is screwed:UVs are wrong and some of the vertices are too.Tried it with triangle strip.

Comment: @MichaelIV: The sphere is not meant to be used with triangle strip.

Comment: You didn't paste it correctly : the indexing part should stop at sector-1 and rings-1. Your other post is correct though. Actually copy pasting it would have been safer !

Answer (score 4):

Paul Bourke actually has a nice introduction to [sphere generation](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/). And as for curved lines, there is no such thing in OpenGL. You can only make them appear curved by adding more intermediate connected points.

Answer (score 4):

There's more than one way to do this: a) icosphere generation and b)UV sphere generation. There may be more methods to do this. Some googling got me [this excellent post on icosphere generation](http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html). I couldn't find UV sphere generation method though.

Comment: It's true, Kahler's page http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html is an absolute classic - it's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

datenwolf's answer is great but contains some error. 
When you use vbo, client states must be disabled after enabled.

Add Three lines to draw code

```
void draw(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x,y,z);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_vertices[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &sphere_texcoords[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, sphere_indices.size()/4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sphere_indices);

    **glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);**

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An iconosphere would do the trick . 
Still , to make a sphere with it , you will have to subdivide it's triangles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there's a great abundance of tutorials on how to make icospheres, but not so much about the method of facet approximation using polar coordinates.

So here's a very slightly edited code sample from the OpenGL Superbible 4th Edition book by Richard S. Wright Jr.

Since it's a very bare bones usage of the fixed-function pipeline (no glDrawElements, etc...) I found it useful for educational purposes.

Stacks are drawn as series of triangle strips. Obviously not the optimal performance, but it works!

```
// For best results, put this in a display list
// Draw a sphere at the origin
void RenderSphere(const float fRadius, const int iStacks, const int iSlices)
    {
        const auto PI = (float)M_PI;
        const auto PIx2 = (float)(M_PI * 2.0);
    
        GLfloat drho = PI / (GLfloat)iStacks;
        GLfloat dtheta = PIx2 / (GLfloat)iSlices;
        GLfloat ds = 1.0f / (GLfloat)iSlices;
        GLfloat dt = 1.0f / (GLfloat)iStacks;
        GLfloat t = 1.0f;
        GLfloat s = 0.0f;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < iStacks; i++)
        {
            const GLfloat rho = (GLfloat)i * drho;
            const GLfloat srho = (GLfloat)(std::sinf(rho));
            const GLfloat crho = (GLfloat)(std::cosf(rho));
            const GLfloat srhodrho = (GLfloat)(std::sinf(rho + drho));
            const GLfloat crhodrho = (GLfloat)(std::cosf(rho + drho));
    
            // Many sources of OpenGL sphere drawing code uses a triangle fan
            // for the caps of the sphere. This however introduces texturing
            // artifacts at the poles on some OpenGL implementations
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            s = 0.0f;
            for (int j = 0; j <= iSlices; j++)
            {
                const GLfloat theta = (j == iSlices) ? 0.0f : j * dtheta;
                const GLfloat stheta = (GLfloat)(-std::sinf(theta));
                const GLfloat ctheta = (GLfloat)(std::cosf(theta));
    
                GLfloat x = stheta * srho;
                GLfloat y = ctheta * srho;
                GLfloat z = crho;
    
                glTexCoord2f(s, t);
                glNormal3f(x, y, z);
                glVertex3f(x * fRadius, y * fRadius, z * fRadius);
    
                x = stheta * srhodrho;
                y = ctheta * srhodrho;
                z = crhodrho;
                glTexCoord2f(s, t - dt);
                s += ds;
                glNormal3f(x, y, z);
                glVertex3f(x * fRadius, y * fRadius, z * fRadius);
            }
            glEnd();
    
            t -= dt;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find back a link to the original online repository of this source code, it's pretty ancient. Feel free to post if you know where to find it !