# How do I create spherical portions using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, grid, geometry

Can someone explain can I bend a grid so it creates a sphere as a result?

I can manage to draw a grid using `triangle_strip`; now I need to draw a portion of a sphere using `triangle_strip`, with a size determined by angle (if angle is 90 degrees, it only creates 1/4 of a sphere).  I also need to be able to change the size of both the hemisphere (to enable possiblity to draw only 1/4 of a hemisphere, also there's no need for using indices).

I am able to draw a sphere using polar coordinates, bit I can't do what is needed by my requirements using polar coordinates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculating a sphere in opengl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946770/calculating-a-sphere-in-opengl)

Comment: Not so much; dupe is for a full sphere; requester seems to want portions of a sphere, not the whole thing.