# OpenGL Drawing a 3d sphere without immediate mode

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using OpenGL to draw a sphere however all of the effort are wasteless because am not used to code in c++, can anyone refer me on a tutorial to build it knowing that I can't use immediate mode in OpenGL I have to do everything by hand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946770/calculating-a-sphere-in-opengl

Comment: Alternatively, using billboards or point sprites, and a fragment shader: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10506172/572743

Comment: am stuck with any open gl version above 3+ and i need to just understand a quick concept about them .. can you please be more specifique

Comment: and if using shaders thats it ! i want something were shaders exist

Comment: Diving into OpenGL without basic knowledge of the language you are using might be a bad idea, especially when you are using the programmable pipeline, instead of the fixed function pipeline functions. It's good that you don't want to use immediate mode though, because it's old and will be deprecated in a few years. If you have the time, I used [these tutorials](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html) to get me going with modern OpenGL.

Comment: [Hello Triangle](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tutorial%2001.html). This is, in principle, all you need. Add 30-40 more vertices to the array, and you have a sphere instead of a triangle. Or, alternatively, add 1 vertex for a rectangle (or use only 1 point and point size) and use a fragment shader that solves `sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` for every fragment and calls `discard` if that is greater than the radius (sphere equation, basic geometry). Adding lighting left as exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: can u guide me with a code ?

Comment: We both linked tutorials with code examples

Comment: [This article](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48) might help you out.

Comment: The tutorials are not very clear when it comes to the orientation of the code its just fragments , my objective is to create a cube and put some texture on it or a sphere

Comment: Or a video tutorial if available

Comment: can nayone help please ?

Comment: This website is not a resource for full working code. The tutorials provide you with everything you need to create your application, if it is not enough, you really should start with some easier things. Have you ever made a medium sized c++ program? I suggest learning c++ first, then OpenGL, and only after that shaders.