# How to draw a sphere in OpenGL ES 2 correctly

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I was wondering what the difference between `gldrawarrays` and `gldrawelements` is?  Also which would you use and when?  Another question i have is how to draw a sphere for the android.  Say i have 360 points on the perimeter for a circle, does that mean i will need 360 * 360 coordinates for a sphere?  That seems to be very expensive, there has to be a better way.  The only way i can think of so far is doing nested for loops.  But that's going to be so much processor time.  Another way i can think of is drawing it and rotating it 360 degrees in a direction.  But then it's not really a true sphere, just a rotated circle.

Comment: I think you should learn more about polygonal graphics before diving into OpenGL...

Comment: You've asked several unrelated questions here. Please break them out into separate questions. Also, look up "tessellation."

Comment: Justin i'm having to self teach it for a directed study.
User thank you, i'll look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I was wondering what the difference between gldrawarrays and gldrawelements is?"

glDrawArrays is used when you deal directly with a stream of vertices, and glDrawElements is used when you use an index buffer, which adds an extra layer of indirection and lets you reference vertices by an index number. You can check out this article for more info on glDrawElements (disclaimer: I wrote the article): http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-eight-an-introduction-to-index-buffer-objects-ibos/

The OpenGL ES manual also has info about these two functions:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml
http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

"Another question i have is how to draw a sphere for the android."

You essentially just have to break it down into triangles. One simple way of doing this is tesselating the sphere using latitude and longitude, like the lines on a globe. You can use a loop with sin and cos to generate the points.

These two questions on Stack Overflow have some example code that should be straightforward to adapt to Android:

- [Creating a 3D sphere in Opengl using Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988686/creating-a-3d-sphere-in-opengl-using-visual-c)
- [calculating a sphere in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946770/calculating-a-sphere-in-opengl?lq=1)

Comment: OH ok that makes so much sense with the draw part.  Since when doing the 3D it's drawArrays if you want color attached to each vertex because you stream them in.  But when doing stuff like GL_Strips or whatnot you can do draw elements because you reference the indices!

Comment: So you need to do the tessellation by hand? I was looking online and couldn't find much about it for OpenGL ES 2, but more for OpenGL 4