# How to find corresponding primitives or vertices for given pixels on the screen in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Suppose a sphere was calculated and drawn using OpenGL such as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946770/calculating-a-sphere-in-opengl) for example.

I am interested in learning, **how one would go about finding the specific vertex that correspond to an arbitrary given pixel on the screen (x,y)?**

I've already read about ray casting and the selection buffer, however, since I need to iterate over a large number of pixels (let's say >10k) and find all the corresponding vertices those solutions didn't seem to be suitable for this kind of stuff.

Ideally, I would like to find a **way that is both fast and modern** in the sense of *modern OpenGL*.

Is there an "out-of-the-box"-solution for this or do I need to write a shader? In either case, any details you could give would be highly appreciated!

Comment: well actually the most pixel you need to iterate through, the most suitable is the selection buffer (well at least it seems to me), because you are using a lot of information among those that you computed in this buffer, why wouldn't it be suitable ?

Comment: Thx for your reply @Guiroux. I've read that the selection buffer is antiquated and may not even be supported by some of the modern graphic chips anymore (being a beginner in all things opengl, I can't really validate that though). Do you happen to have a good resource handy on how to work with the selection buffer for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an integer "face ID" vertex attribute, make it the same for each vertex of a given triangle
2. Pass the face ID through the VS to the FS & write it to an integer FBO
3. Read back the FBO pixels (use PBOs for async FBO readback) in the desired location(s), giving the face ID at each point

Comment: Thank you @genpfault, I shall try this and report back.