# Connecting Sphere Vertices OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, indices, vertices

I am trying to render a sphere in OpenGL using GL_TRIANGLES.
Here is an image of what I am getting with the code below..
[Bad Sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5jiU.jpg)

This is supposed to be a unit sphere.

I have derived the vertices from the basic sphere approximations from 
[wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Here is the code that I created to render the unit sphere..
Please let me know where I am going wrong

```
void createGreenSphere(mat4 modelView){
  std::vector< Vertex > v;
  int numSphereSlices = 12;
  int numSphereSegments = 12;
  float theta = 0;
  float phi = 0;
  float phiDelt   =  (2*PI) / numSphereSegments;
  float thetaDelt = PI / numSphereSlices;
  float* vertices = new float[numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments*4];
  float* normals = new float[numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments*4];
  float* colors = new float[numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments*3];
  int colorCnt = 0;
  int vertCnt = 0;
  for(int heightCnt = 0; heightCnt < numSphereSlices; heightCnt++){
    theta += thetaDelt;
    phi = 0;
    for(int widthCnt = 0; widthCnt < numSphereSegments; widthCnt++){
      phi += phiDelt; 
      vertices[vertCnt] = sin(theta)*cos(phi);
      normals[vertCnt] = vertices[vertCnt];
      vertCnt++;
      vertices[vertCnt] = sin(theta)*sin(phi);
      normals[vertCnt] = vertices[vertCnt];
      vertCnt++;
      vertices[vertCnt] = cos(theta);
      normals[vertCnt] = vertices[vertCnt];
      vertCnt++;
      vertices[vertCnt] = 1.0;
      normals[vertCnt] = vertices[vertCnt];
      vertCnt++;
      colors[colorCnt] = 0.0;
      colorCnt++;
      colors[colorCnt] = 1.0;
      colorCnt++;
      colors[colorCnt] = 0.0;
      colorCnt++;
     }
  }
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertCnt-1 * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);                                                  
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorCnt-1 * sizeof(float), colors, GL_STREAM_DRAW);    

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertCnt-1 * sizeof(float), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

  unsigned short* indices = new unsigned short[numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments*6];
  int indexCnt = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<numSphereSlices;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<numSphereSegments;j++){
      indices[indexCnt] = j + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
      indices[indexCnt] = j+1 + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
      indices[indexCnt] = numSphereSegments+j + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
      indices[indexCnt] = numSphereSegments+j+1 + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
      indices[indexCnt] = numSphereSegments+j + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
      indices[indexCnt] = j+1 + numSphereSegments*i;
      indexCnt++;
    }
  }

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);                                                      
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments*6) *      sizeof(unsigned short), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  delete [] indices;

  glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelView[0][0]);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numSphereSlices*numSphereSegments, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


  glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);
 }
```

I am not sure whether the problem is in creating the vertices or linking the indices..

Comment: everything looks fine. I guess something is wrong with your view matrix. for start, try using the transpose of the view matrix you are using now.

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue either, I was making other shapes just find such as cubes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and Pasting for your reference some code I originally wrote in [Creating a 3D sphere in Opengl using Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988686/how-do-i-create-a-3d-sphere-in-opengl-using-visual-c/5989676#5989676)

```
class SolidSphere
{
protected
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    std::vector<GLfloat> normals;
    std::vector<GLfloat> texcoords;
    std::vector<GLushort> indices;

public:
    void SolidSphere(float radius, unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors)
    {
        float const R = 1./(float)(rings-1);
        float const S = 1./(float)(sectors-1);
        int r, s;

        sphere_vertices.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        sphere_normals.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        sphere_texcoords.resize(rings * sectors * 2);
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator v = sphere_vertices.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator n = sphere_normals.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator t = sphere_texcoords.begin();
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
                float const y = sin( -M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R );
                float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );
                float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );

                *t++ = s*S;
                *t++ = r*R;

                *v++ = x * radius;
                *v++ = y * radius;
                *v++ = z * radius;

                *n++ = x;
                *n++ = y;
                *n++ = z;
        }

        sphere_indices.resize(rings * sectors * 4);
        std:vector<GLushort>::iterator i = sphere_indices.begin();
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
                *i++ = r * sectors + s;
                *i++ = r * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I double checked how I created the indices and its seems to be identical to yours except for a little differences because it uses Triangles rather than Quads.  Implementing it in this way, I am still getting the same output.  I keep thinking back to creating the vertices, but it seems also to be the same as you do, except for maybe a little syntax differences.  Any other suggestions??