# OpenGL gaps within sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, geometry, glm-math

I have recently been trying to render a 3D sphere in OpenGL using triangles. I have been testing and modifying code from various websites and have finally found a winning combination. The only problem is that there are visible gaps in the sphere. Any thoughts on what would be causing this?

**Code to render sphere**

```
float Slices = 30;
float Stacks = 60;
float Radius = 20.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= Stacks; ++i){

    float V   = i / (float) Stacks;
    float phi = V * glm::pi <float> ();

    for (int j = 0; j <= Slices; ++j){

        float U = j / (float) Slices;
        float theta = U * (glm::pi <float> () * 4);

        float x = cosf (theta) * sinf (phi);
        float y = cosf (phi);
        float z = sinf (theta) * sinf (phi);
        x *= Radius;
        y *= Radius;
        z *= Radius;

        Vertex *v = new Vertex {{x,y,z},    //Position
                                {255,0,0}}; //Color
        screenToBuffer(v, 1);
        delete []v;
    }
}
```

**Problem**
[image]

Comment: what does `screenToBuffer(v, 1);` do?

Comment: Sends the vertex to the VBO.

Comment: Where's the rendering code?

Comment: The point calculation looks fine. But in addition, you'll need an index array that defines the correct connectivity to create triangles from these points. Either that, or you'll have to repeat points.

Answer (score -1):

Try and set it to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP​

What might be the problem is that it considers each group of three vertices to be only one triangle.

Like so

```
Indices:     0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
Triangles:  {0 1 2} {3 4 5}
```

The GL_TRIAGLE_STRIP will do this.

```
 Indices:     0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 
 Triangles:  {0 1 2}
               {1 2 3}  drawing order is (2 1 3) to maintain proper winding
                 {2 3 4}
                   {3 4 5}
```

---

See this answer for a proper way to do it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958376/1943599

Comment: Simply drawing a triangle strip with the points shown in the OP's code would still look about equally wrong. The points are not calculated in an order that would be correct to render a sphere with triangle strips.

Comment: I just assumed he had cull face disabled.