# lighting the sun giving absurd results

Tags: opengl, lighting

I am trying to develop space simulator. I am trying to use sun as the light source. My problem is that the lighting dosent work as expected. Maybe i am using the wrong calculation for the normals. I am using a single "createsphere" function to create a sphere, and then use different coordinates and sizes to display them. The problem is that all the spheres on the screen show almost the same effect(i.e i've applied only one light source but it seems to have been implemented to all the spheres) .and also the light rotates along with them. I am not sure where the problem is ...i am posting my code ...

the code for sphere display

```
void DisplaySphere_sun (double R, GLuint texture)
{

 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int b,m = 0;
glScalef (0.0125 * R, 0.0125 * R, 0.0125 * R);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);


for ( b = 0; b <VertexCount; b++)
{
    /*if((b%3)==0)
    {
        glNormal3f(normal[m].x,normal[m].y,normal[m].z);
        m++;
    }*/

    glTexCoord2f (VERTEX[b].U, VERTEX[b].V);
    /*glNormal3f(-VERTEX[b].X, -VERTEX[b].Y, -VERTEX[b].Z);*/
    glVertex3f (VERTEX[b].Y, VERTEX[b].X, -VERTEX[b].Z);
}

m = 0;

for ( b = 0; b <VertexCount; b++)
{
    /*if((b%3)==0)
    {
        glNormal3f(normal[m].x,normal[m].y,normal[m].z);
        m++;
    }*/

    glTexCoord2f (VERTEX[b].U, -VERTEX[b].V);
/*  glNormal3f(-VERTEX[b].X, -VERTEX[b].Y, -VERTEX[b].Z);*/
    glVertex3f (VERTEX[b].Y, VERTEX[b].X, VERTEX[b].Z);
}


glEnd();
//glRotatef(120,0,0,0);

}
```

the code for creating a sphere

```
void CreateSphere (double R, double X, double Y, double Z) {
int n,m;
double a;
double b;
n = 0;
m = 0;


for( b = 0; b <= 90 - space; b+=space){

for( a = 0; a <= 360 - space; a+=space)
{
    VERTEX[n].X = R * sin((a) / 180 * PI) * sin((b) / 180 * PI) - X;
    VERTEX[n].Y = R * cos((a) / 180 * PI) * sin((b) / 180 * PI) + Y;
    VERTEX[n].Z = R * cos((b) / 180 * PI) - Z;
    VERTEX[n].V = (2 * b) / 360;
    VERTEX[n].U = (a) / 360;

    n++;
    VERTEX[n].X = R * sin((a) / 180 * PI) * sin((b + space) / 180 * PI) - X;
    VERTEX[n].Y = R * cos((a) / 180 * PI) * sin((b + space) / 180 * PI) + Y;
    VERTEX[n].Z = R * cos((b + space) / 180 * PI) - Z;
    VERTEX[n].V = (2 * (b + space)) / 360;
    VERTEX[n].U = (a) / 360;

    n++;
    VERTEX[n].X = R * sin((a + space) / 180 * PI) * sin((b) / 180 * PI) - X;
    VERTEX[n].Y = R * cos((a + space) / 180 * PI) * sin((b) / 180 * PI) + Y;
    VERTEX[n].Z = R * cos((b) / 180 * PI) - Z;
    VERTEX[n].V = (2 * b) / 360;
    VERTEX[n].U = (a + space) / 360;
    n++;


    VERTEX[n].X = R * sin((a + space) / 180 * PI) * sin((b + space) /180 * PI) - X;
    VERTEX[n].Y = R * cos((a + space) / 180 * PI) * sin((b + space) /180 * PI) + Y;
    VERTEX[n].Z = R * cos((b + space) / 180 * PI) - Z;
    VERTEX[n].V = (2 * (b + space)) / 360;
    VERTEX[n].U = (a + space) / 360;
n++;
}

}
}
```

and code for lighting the sun

```
glPushMatrix();

 gluLookAt (0.0, 10.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //defines a viewing transformation.

 // Now translate to the sun 

  glTranslatef(0.0, -7.0, 3.0);

  /* For LIGHT0 */

 GLfloat lightZeroPosition[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

 /*GLfloat lightvec[] = {0.5f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f};*/

 GLfloat lightZeroColor[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};


 GLfloat amb[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

 GLfloat spec[] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1};

 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightZeroPosition);

 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightZeroColor);

 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, spec);

  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

 glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);

 DisplaySphere(5,textures);

// function to display the sun

 glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: @NickLH i can't add a pic because of less reputation points

Comment: @NickLH : image links : http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=400&filename=Untitled.png                       http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=401&filename=untitled2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled, why you don't draw the sun at the orign of the solar system? The sun is a star, and stars carry over 95% of their stellar systems mass, so the center of gravity of the whole thing is within the sun for most planets (only Jupiter has so much mass, that it shifts the center of gravity slightly outside the sun's photosphere radius).

As for your lighting problem, one normally doesn't illuminate light sources. Just switch off lighting when drawing the sun. Then when drawing the planets place the light source within the sun. OpenGL is not a global renderer, i.e. after you've drawn something, it completely forgets about it, i.e. you won't get any lighting interactions between the things you draw (means also, no shadows for free).

This is how I'd draw a solar system (pseudocode):

```
draw_solar_system():
    glPushMatrix()

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
    draw_origin_sphere(sun_radius)

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (0., 0., 0., 1.))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (1., 1., 1., 1.))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0., 0., 0., 1.))

    for p in planets:
        glPushMatrix()

        glRotatef(p.orbital_inclination, p.axis_of_orbital_inclination)
        glRotatef(p.orbital_angle, 0., 1., 0.)
        glTranslatef(p.orbit_radius, 1., 0. 0.)
        glRotate(p.axial_of_inclination, p.axis_of_axis_inclination)
        glRotate(p.time_of_day, 0., 1., 0.)

        draw_origin_sphere(p.radius)

        glPopMatrix()
    glPopMatrix()
```

Comment: thanks .. you advise surely helped with lighting .. but i am not getting shading properly .. maybe i am calculating wrong normals...

Comment: @dvyas: In the case of a sphere centered at 0 (and only a sphere!) it happens that the normal is equal to the vertex position. Anyway your sphere drawing cose it suboptimal. This is what I had to write about the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5989676/524368