# Ellipsoid to Sphere in OSG

Tags: openscenegraph

I have been practicing some openSceneGraph examples provided by OSG. One of the example, I came across text on the ellipsoid.

```
osgText::Text* createText(osg::EllipsoidModel* ellipsoid, double latitude, double longitude, double height, const std::string& str)
{
    double X, Y, Z;
    ellipsoid->convertLatLongHeightToXYZ(osg::DegreesToRadians(latitude), osg::DegreesToRadians(longitude), height, X, Y, Z);
```

This works well in my case.then I thought to do the same with the sphere. In this example, the ellipsoid drawn basing on the lat, long and height. I want to draw the sphere with radius which depends on the window size / screen size. Unfortunately I failed to see which converts the screen coordinates to sphere size in the osg::Sphere class.

Some one can help me, to solve this. There might be some thing which converts this, may be i did not come across because of my less experience.

Cheers,
Inna.

Answer (score 0):

osg::Sphere is not a geospatial model like osg::EllipsoidModel.

Just create an osg::EllipsoidModel with both Radii (equator and polar) the same as the sphere radius you wish, and use osg::EllipsoidModel.

Comment: Hi Mr. @XenonofArcticus  I have tried as you said. But I am not getting the result as sphere.
**double latitude = 360.0;"
'double longitude = 360.0;//-100'**

and then I am using it for Ellipsoid model
**'geode->addDrawable(createText(ellipsoid, latitude, lgnt, 0, textList[t % textList.size()]));'**

Comment: Am I missing any transmission ?

Comment: Latitude of 360 is a non-sensical number. 

Show me some actual code of how you are creating the EllipsoidModel and using it. Also, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. I suggest we continue it on the osg-users mailing list, and you delete this question.

Comment: Hi Mr.@XenonofArcticus  I have posted  the question on the osg forum as you said. Currently, I am bale to draw the sphere using some code from  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433443/creating-a-sphere-using-osggeometry-in-openscenegraph)