# How to use c# windows as glut window?

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

I want to display `GlutSolidSphere` in c# window. I am using `Tao Framework`. Since you have to create `GlutWindow` to display the `Glut Objects`. I do not want to create this `GlutWindow` but I want to use c# window to display `Glut Objects`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an OpenGL context on the window. You can do this via Tao.SimpleOpenGlControl (windows-only) or [OpenTK.GLControl](http://www.opentk.com) (cross-platform).

As datenwolf suggested, once you have an OpenGL context you can render GLUT shapes at will.

Comment: thanks bro. I have solve problem. what you are saying is describing in thin link (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~crawfis/cse581/Homework/TaoSetup.html) and second thing is that I didn't need to draw 3d Sphere using Glut. but we can also draw it by GluSpere function. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this?

glutSolidSphere actually doesn't depend on GLUT being used for the window. But why bother, drawing a sphere is simple. It's easy to write it yourself (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989676/524368) and there exist ready to use libraries as well.

No need to use GLUT.