# OpenGL/C++ 3D sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

Below you find the widely spread code for manually creating a sphere in OpenGL. I modified it a little, so that it looks more complete now, but still can't get it to work. It only produces a white window. Any ideas what am I missing?

```
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define M_PI_2 1.57079632679489661923

int const win_width = 512;
int const win_height = 512;

using namespace std;

class SolidSphere
{
protected:
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    std::vector<GLfloat> normals;
    std::vector<GLfloat> texcoords;
    std::vector<GLushort> indices;

public:
    SolidSphere(float radius, unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors)
    {
        float const R = 1./(float)(rings-1);
        float const S = 1./(float)(sectors-1);
        int r, s;

        vertices.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        normals.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
        texcoords.resize(rings * sectors * 2);
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator v = vertices.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator n = normals.begin();
        std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator t = texcoords.begin();
        for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) {
            for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
                float const y = sin(-M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R);
                float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin(M_PI * r * R);
                float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin(M_PI * r * R);

                *t++ = s*S;
                *t++ = r*R;

                *v++ = x * radius;
                *v++ = y * radius;
                *v++ = z * radius;

                *n++ = x;
                *n++ = y;
                *n++ = z;
            }
        }

        indices.resize(rings * sectors * 4);
        std::vector<GLushort>::iterator i = indices.begin();
        for (r = 0; r < rings-1; r++) {
            for(s = 0; s < sectors-1; s++) {
                *i++ = r * sectors + s;
                *i++ = r * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
                *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + s;
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normals[0]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &texcoords[0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indices[0]);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
};

SolidSphere sphere(1, 12, 24);

void display()
{
    float const win_aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, win_aspect, 1, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

#ifdef DRAW_WIREFRAME
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
#endif
    sphere.draw(0, 0, -5);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(win_width, win_height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("3D Sphere");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: whitewindow]

Comment: if you specify the no. of rings and sectors in the constructor you might as well store the data in fixed arrays rather than vectors... it just adds to the complication.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah No it actually doesn't. It means he'd have to write a destructor too.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: Fixed arrays would be arrays with their size determined at compile time. This is definitely not the case for this class. But if you do the allocation using `new[]` you've got the burden of also `delete[]`-ing it. And internally `std::vector` does just the same, with the nice addition that it's RAII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to glDrawElements must look like this

```
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indices[0]);
```

Also since the `draw` method is written inline, no `SolidSphere::` must prefix it (that would be valid only if the method is defined outside the class.

The code you posted originates in this StackOverflow answer I gave over a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989676/524368

And if you look at this answer the definition of `draw` and the glDrawElements call therein are correct and any edits to the code in the answer were to other parts, but not this. So wherever you took the code from, it got altered with mistakes.

Comment: I made a noobish mistake. I put `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);` instead of `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);`. Now it's fine.