# gluNewQuadric() is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: opengl, deprecated

Xcode warns me that `gluNewQuadric()` is deprecated. What should I be using instead? I've looked all over and haven't found any suggestions.

Also, if it's worth anything, I was planning on using `gluSphere()`, which apparently is also deprecated, so I'm looking for a solution to replace that. I really don't want to use `glutSolidSphere()`.

Comment: Well, just draw the sphere yourself, it's not that hard. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5989676/524368

Comment: So there isn't a GLU replacement subroutine?

Comment: No. Why should there be one? GLU never was very useful to begin with, so why bother?

Comment: Is there any single GLU function that isn't deprecated?

Comment: @keltar: Some of GLU isn't technically related to OpenGL at all, like the tessellator. Not a single one of the things the GLU tessellator does invokes a GL API call. When Xcode warns that it's deprecated, it means that Apple will not be supporting the library into the future (not necessarily that it uses deprecated parts of OpenGL). They could decide tomorrow that OS X 10.10 won't support it if they wanted. @MarcusMcLean: Incidentally, Apple has also deprecated GLUT, so `glutSolidSphere (...)` is not a good replacement either.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman well yes, I was talking about Xcode of course. What I meant is if all GLU functions considered deprecated, there is no point in looking for replacement within GLU.